# Encrypt traffic using Ingress and TLS

Tags: kubernetes, ssl, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I have a service named mocksvc in Kubernetes. This service listens port on 4000, REQUIRES TLS for incoming requests and checks and verifies TLS itself. I want to create an ingress (using NGINX controller) to Encrypt traffic using TLS, so that other pods can connect to mocksvc through this ingress without TLS. In other words, I want something like this:

Other pods(plaintext) -> Ingress(encrypt using TLS) -> mocksvc

Most online resources describe the opposite situation where ingress terminates SSL and the traffic between ingress and target service is in plaintext. Can you help me with creating an ingress config for this purpose? I have cert and private key files of mocksvc and have created a kubetnetes secret using them called mock-tls.

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough: "true"
  name: mock-ingress
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - mocksvc
      secretName: mock-tls
  rules:
    - host: mocksvc
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: mocksvc
                port:
                  number: 4000
```

**UPDATE:**
After comments from Fariya Rahmat and larsks, I made some changes to the ingress as follows:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"
  name: mock-ingress
spec:
  rules:
    - host: mocksvc
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: mocksvc
                port:
                  number: 4000
```

I assume that the ingress will not require TLS anymore for incoming data, but will use TLS to connect to the backend service. The problem is, since the certificate of the service is a self-signed certificate, the ingress cannot properly encrypt the data. Any ideas on that?!

Comment: Have you gone through this document on [How to secure applications running on kubernetes](https://medium.com/avmconsulting-blog/how-to-secure-applications-on-kubernetes-ssl-tls-certificates-8f7f5751d788#:~:text=You%20can%20secure%20an%20application,crt%20and%20tls)? Can you try creating ingress with TLS as given in the document without annotations? To troubleshoot further you can also check this github [link](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/main/docs/user-guide/tls.md#ssl-passthrough).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to configure ingress to direct traffic to an https backend using https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459015/how-to-configure-ingress-to-direct-traffic-to-an-https-backend-using-https)

Comment: Just updated the question

Comment: Could you please elaborate on your issue as the information provided is not sufficient. In the meantime please have a look into this SO [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14584787)